# System Level Resources not resolving when opening a Windows Phone 7.1 Project in Blend 4

Tags: windows-phone-7, expression, expression-blend

I have the following installed on a clean Windows 7 SP1 setup:

- VS 2010 Ultimate
- VS2010 SP1
- Windows Phone 7.1 SDK
- Expression Studio 4 Ultimate
- Expression Blend 4 SP1

When I create a phone project in VS, all works.
When I load that same project (originally created in VS) I get resource not resolving errors for `PhoneTextNormalStyle`, `PhoneTextTitle1Style`, `PhoneForgroundBrush`, `PhoneFontSizeNormal` and `PhoneFontFamilyNormal` which follow this format:

```
The resource 'PhoneTextNormalStyle' could not be resolved
```

When I create a project in Blend, all works. When I load that project into VA, all works

I have tried uninstalling the reinstalling the bits in every order imaginable - maybe some sort of security Issue?

Comment: You load the same project, in where? BLend or VS?

Comment: this has been edited. When I create a project in Blend it works in Blend/VS. When I create a project in VS it works in VS but i get the above error when I load that project into Blend

Comment: Did you try building the project in blend?

Comment: yes - building in Blend just opens the folder in IE for the VS-created app..the Blend created app opens in the emulator as expected

Answer (score 1):

It appears blend is missing the Theme Resource Dictionaries you're trying to reference.

When you check your Resources tab in Blend (normally top right corner) what resource dictionaries appear available? More importantly, are the paths to your resource dictionaries correct in your app.xaml? Since VS uses Cider Designer instead of the same design presenter that blend does, these contingencies can occur often. Although I hear VS 2011 will use the same design presenter as blend...

Anyhow as I'm reading this I just noticed the date it was posted. If you're still having this issue then please reply and I can definitely help you resolve it when I get home from the office where I have access to my phone projects. Cheers!

Comment: I have the same issues with Windows Phone styles as the people above. I'm using a 64-bit Windows 8 Pro machine. I also have a 32-bit Windows 8 Pro laptop running the same tools, but I don't have this problem there.